# What's the WordPress hook that is the "earliest" in execution?

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I've used the WordPress hook, `init`, to execute custom code early in WordPress, but is there another hook that executes earlier than that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If [this page in the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) is accurate, you have 10 choices for hooks that occur before `init`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the earliest-running [Action Hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) in Wordpress 4.x is  [`muplugins_loaded`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/muplugins_loaded). That hook is called after all activated [Must-Use Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) have been loaded.

In the event that `mupluginst_loaded` [might not trigger](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162862/how-to-get-wordpress-hook-run-sequence), the [`registered_taxonomy`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/registered_taxonomy) plugin fires right after that.